# Python Pandas create new column if other columns in the same row match certain string

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on Python Pandas. Dataframe is like:

| Group | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11abc | q | q | q |
| q | q | q | q |
| q | 22abc | q | q |

I would like to create an additional column. If in the same row, there is an item matched substring "abc", the exact value will be copied to the new column.

Expected result:

```
|Group |  Group1 |  Group2 |  Group3 | NewColumn |
|------|---------|---------|---------|-----------|
|11abc |    q    |    q    |    q    | 11abc     |
|q     |    q    |    q    |    q    | (no value)|
|q     |  22abc  |    q    |    q    | 22abc     |
```

I googled a while and find out I can use `pd.series.str.contains('abc')` to return TRUE. Then I planned to to loop through the columns. First of all I tried one column first by:

```
IF df_target[df_target['Group'].str.contains('abc')]:
    df_target['NewColumn'] = df_target['Group']
```

However, I encounter the error "`Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`". I have a step backward and I am not sure if I am on the correct direction. I would like to check with the community what would be the appropriate way in doing this kind of data transformation task in Pandas?

Many thanks..

Comment: There is possible one or multiple match per row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If posible multiple match you can filter rows with join by `,`:

```
df['NewColumn'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.str.contains('abc')]), axis=1)
print (df)
   Group Group1 Group2 Group3 NewColumn
0  11abc      q      q      q     11abc
1      q      q      q      q          
2      q  22abc      q      q     22abc
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, stack and perform your match:

```
s = df.stack()
out = df.join(s[s.str.contains('abc')]
               .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
               .rename('NewColumn'))
```

output:

```
   Group Group1 Group2 Group3 NewColumn
0  11abc      q      q      q     11abc
1      q      q      q      q       NaN
2      q  22abc      q      q     22abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for both mozway and jezael. I tried both method and they both work.

A small note, I also add in a parameter in str.contains('abc',na=False) as I have na in actual data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).